# Create groups of users with conditions

Tags: php, symfony

I have a group entity. This group entity has a "nombre" field which is the wanted size of the group, "jour1" and "horaire1" which are first DateTime of an exam for the group and "jour2" and "horaire2" which are second DateTime of an exam for the group.

There are around 40 groups and only 4 different pairs of DateTime (Monday 17:30-Wednesday 18:30, Monday 18:30-Wednesday 17:30, Tuesday 17:30-Thursday 18:30, Tuesday 18:30-Thursday 17:30).

I have another entity, DemandeGroupe. This entity allows users to ask for a specific DateTime of exam and/or to be with another specific user in the group. Users can ask for multiple users.

I want all users to be divided into these groups  with some conditions :

1) Users asking to be with another user and asking a specific DateTime have to be in the same group of the asked DateTime.

2) Users only asking a specific user have to be in the same group as this user.

3) Users only asking a specific DateTime have to be in a group of this DateTime.

4) Users which didn't asked anything have to be divided into groups randomly.

5) Groups are not sized the same so all groups has to comply with the size defined in "nombre" field, so number of users in each group has to be inferior or equal to "nombre" and all groups have to be filled in the same time (I don't want the last group to be filled with less users if there's less users than space in groups).

I can't find a way to comply with all these conditions in the same time.

**GroupeComposition entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string")
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="salle_composition", type="string")
 */
private $salleComposition;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="salle_correction", type="string")
 */
private $salleCorrection;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="integer")
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="jour1", type="string")
 */
private $jour1;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="horaire_jour1", type="string")
 */
private $horaireJour1;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="jour2", type="string")
 */
private $jour2;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="horaire_jour2", type="string")
 */
private $horaireJour2;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="type_tutore", type="string")
 */
private $typeTutore;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="specialite", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $specialite;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\PACES\UserBundle\Entity\Tutore", mappedBy="groupeComposition")
 */
protected $tutores;
```

**DemandeGroupe entity :**

```
**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\UserBundle\Entity\Tutore", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tutoreSource;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\UserBundle\Entity\Tutore", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $tutoreDemande;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="jour", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $jour;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="horaire", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $horaire;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="raison", type="string")
 */
private $raison;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="acceptee", type="boolean", nullable=true, options={"default":null})
 */
private $acceptee;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this piece of code :

```
$demandes = $em->getRepository(DemandeGroupe::class)->findBy(['acceptee' => true, 'semestre' => $semestre]);
    $groupes = $em->getRepository(GroupeComposition::class)->findAll();

    $groupesOfCompo = [];
    foreach ($groupes as $groupe) {
        $groupesOfCompo[] = ['objet' => $groupe,
                        'nombre' => $groupe->getNombre(),
                        'jour1' => $groupe->getJour1(). ' '. $groupe->getHoraireJour1(),
                        'jour2' => $groupe->getJour2(). ' '. $groupe->getHoraireJour2()];
    }

    // Array to exclude these users afterwards
    $tutoresWithDemande = [];

    shuffle($demandes);

    foreach ($demandes as $demande) {
        $tutore1 = $demande->getTutoreSource();
        $tutoresWithDemande[] = $tutore1->getId();
        $tutore2 = null;
        if ($demande->getTutoreDemande()) {
            $tutore2 = $demande->getTutoreDemande();
            $tutoresWithDemande[] = $tutore2->getId();
        }

        $dateDemande = null;
        if ($demande->getJour() && $demande->getHoraire()) {
            $dateDemande = $demande->getJour() . ' ' . $demande->getHoraire();
        }

        if ($dateDemande) {

            // Array of possible groups for current user
            $groupes = [];

            foreach ($groupesOfCompo as $groupe) {
                if ($groupe['jour1'] == $dateDemande || $groupe['jour2'] == $dateDemande) {
                    // Check if there's enough space left in group && if group is possible for this user
                    if ((($tutore2 && 0 <= $groupe['nombre'] - 2) ||
                            (!$tutore2 && 0 <= $groupe['nombre'] - 1))
                        && $tutore1->getSituation() === $groupe['objet']->getTypeTutore()
                    ) {
                        $groupes[] = $groupe;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Get size of each group
            $effectifs = array_column($groupes, 'nombre');
            // Get max group size
            $max = max($effectifs);
            // Get group with max group size
            $max_array = $groupes[array_search($max, $effectifs)];

            $tutore1->setGroupeComposition($max_array['objet']);
            $em->persist($tutore1);

            if ($tutore2) {
                $tutore2->setGroupeComposition($max_array['objet']);
                $em->persist($tutore2);
            }

            // Get back group from initial array to decrease space left in group
            foreach ($groupesOfCompo as &$a) {
                if ($a['objet'] === $max_array['objet']) {
                    if ($tutore2) {
                        $a['nombre'] -= 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        $a['nombre']--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $groupes = [];
            foreach ($groupesOfCompo as $groupe) {
                if ((($tutore2 && 0 <= $groupe['nombre'] - 2) ||
                        (!$tutore2 && 0 <= $groupe['nombre'] - 1))
                    && $tutore1->getSituation() === $groupe['objet']->getTypeTutore())
                {
                    $groupes[] = $groupe;
                }
            }
            $effectifs = array_column($groupes, 'nombre');
            $max = max($effectifs);
            $max_array = $groupes[array_search($max, $effectifs)];

            $tutore1->setGroupeComposition($max_array['objet']);
            $em->persist($tutore1);

            if ($tutore2) {
                $tutore2->setGroupeComposition($max_array['objet']);
                $em->persist($tutore2);
            }

            foreach ($groupesOfCompo as &$a) {
                if ($a['objet'] === $max_array['objet']) {
                    if ($tutore2) {
                        $a['nombre'] -= 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        $a['nombre']--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Get users without DemandeGroupe
    $groupeSalle = $em->getRepository(Groupe::class)->findOneBy(['nom' => 'Salle']);
    $tutoresWithoutDemande = $em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findAllExceptExcluded($groupeSalle, $tutoresWithDemande);

    shuffle($tutoresWithoutDemande);

    foreach ($tutoresWithoutDemande as $tutore) {
        // Pour chaque groupe de composition
        foreach ($groupesOfCompo as $groupe) {

            if (0 <= $groupe['nombre'] - 1 && $tutore->getSituation() === $groupe['objet']->getTypeTutore()) {
                $groupes[] = $groupe;
            }
        }

        $effectifs = array_column($groupes, 'nombre');
        $max = max($effectifs);
        $max_array = $groupes[array_search($max, $effectifs)];

        $tutore->setGroupeComposition($max_array['objet']);
        $em->persist($tutore);

        foreach ($groupesOfCompo as &$a) {
            if ($a['objet'] === $max_array['objet']) {
                $a['nombre']--;
            }
        }
    }
$em->flush();
```